# Converting string array into json

Tags: java, json, arrays

My String array has the following output each time it iterates through the loop

```
apple
orange
```

I want to convert my string array output to json format/jsonarray. I tried but it gives output as

```
{"fruits",apple}
{"fruits",orange}
```

I want my output as

```
{"fruits": [
{

  "1": "apple"
}
{

  "2": "orange"
}
```

I tried the below code

```
String[] strArray = new String[] {newString};
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
        //json.put("fruits", newString);

       //System.out.println(json);
        for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(strArray[i]+"\t");
               json.put("",strArray[i]);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
  for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++)
    {
        JSONObject fruit = new JSONObject();
        fruit.put(""+i,strArray[i]); 
        array.put(fruit);
    }
   obj.put("Fruits",array);
   System.Out.Println(obj.toString(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :-

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("key", "value");
String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
```

I hope this will work for you.